# How To Disable VSCode Git Rebase UI

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-rebase, gitlens

How do I disable VS Code's [Interactive Rebase UI](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_git-rebase-command)?

[image: VSCode Interactive Rebase]

I'm hoping to return to the previous experience where running `git rebase -i` opens a text file into VS Code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110819), this is actually caused by the GitLens extension, not VSCode.  You can fix it by adding this to your settings.json:

```json
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
  "git-rebase-todo": "default"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This changed in GitLens version 11.0.2: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/discussions/1260

> To disable the *Interactive Rebase Editor* use the `GitLens: Disable Interactive Rebase Editor` command from the command palette (`ctrl+shift+p` or `cmd+shift+p`).